# Golang memory allocation for string copy memory addresses

Tags: go, memory-management

I am currently reading the Go Programming Language book which describes that a copy of a string or a substring has similar memory addresses.

```
s := "hello"
c := s

fmt.Println(&s, &c) // prints 0xc000010230 0xc000010240
```

My question is, shouldn't `&c` be the same as `&s` since it `c` is an exact copy ?

```
               RAM
      Address    |     Value
 &s 0xc000010230 |    "hello" <----- s
 &c 0xc000010240 |    "hello" <----- c
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. So each instance points to an immutable backing array of bytes. Even with the address of a string you cannot change the individual characters within that memory block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`c` and `s` are actually two *distinct* string *headers*. But both of them point to the same `"hello"`.

```golang
sh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
ch := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&c))
fmt.Println(sh.Data, ch.Data)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Ckl0P3g4nVo

---

The `Data` field of the string header points to the first `byte` in the string and the `Len` field of the string header indicates the length of the string. You can use that information to confirm that the string header is pointing to the original string.

```golang
sh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
for i := 0; i < sh.Len; i++ {
    sp := (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(sh.Data + uintptr(i)))
    fmt.Printf("%p = %c\n", sp, *sp)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/LFfdxxARw1f

Comment: Ok I read in the book that all variables have a distinct memory address. Does that apply here ?

Comment: Yes, `c` and `s` are variables. `&c` and `&s` produce pointers pointing to different addresses as you have already observed and described in your question. Of course it applies.

Comment: Thanks, I havent read about reflection so I guess I'll keep this code in mind